# get the value from a dict using filter

Tags: ansible

I have a dictionary, not a dict list, let's say I read a dict from JSON file something.json has content `{"a": "b"}`

I would like to extract the value using a filter, so I could process that with more filters

```yaml
# Expecting 'lookup('file', 'something.json') | from_json | ???' gives the value 'b'
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('file', 'something.json') | from_json | ??? | urlencode() }}"
```

I searched that all other examples are for dict list, but I only have a dict here

Comment: I don't understand why are you need a filter.
You can call just like that ```{{ var.a | urlencode() }}```

Comment: => `{{ var | dict2items | map(attribute='value') | map('urlencode') }}`

Comment: Ah I edited the question a bit to cater to my scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the file below

```yaml
shell> cat something.json 
{"a": "b"}
```

---

Q: ***"Get the value from a dict using a filter."***

A: I read your question: *"Get the value from a hash without knowing the key."* There are many options:

1. Include the variable from the file to a dictionary, e.g. *d1*, and display the first value

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: something.json
        name: d1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ d1.values()|first }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: b

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

2. You can put the declarations into the [*vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    d1: "{{ lookup('file', 'something.json') }}"
    v1: "{{ d1.values()|first }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: v1
    - debug:
        var: d1|type_debug
    - debug:
        var: d1
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  v1: b

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  d1|type_debug: dict

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  d1:
    a: b

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

3. Use *json_query*

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    d1: "{{ lookup('file', 'something.json') }}"
    v1: "{{ d1|json_query('values(@)')|first }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: v1
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  v1: b

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

All the above options assume the file is available at the controller. If the file is at the remote host:

4. Use [*slurp*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html#ansible-builtin-slurp-module-slurps-a-file-from-remote-nodes)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    d1: "{{ out.content|b64decode }}"
    v1: "{{ d1.values()|first }}"
  tasks:
    - slurp:
        src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/something.json"
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: v1
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [slurp] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  v1: b

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

5. You can also simply register the output of *cat*

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    d1: "{{ out.stdout }}"
    v1: "{{ d1.values()|first }}"
  tasks:
    - command:
        cmd: "cat something.json"
        chdir: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: v1
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  v1: b

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Zeitounator, I sorted out using

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('file', 'something.json') | from_json | dict2items | map(attribute='value')  | urlencode() }}"
```